# How to use global variables in an ISR (Interrupt Handler)

Tags: c, embedded

The intent is to use a variable, an int to count instances of the interrupt and do things accordingly within the ISR accordingly to the value. So, I declared it as `extern volatile int counter` and then also declared it in my interrupts.c file (which is where my interrupts such as `SysTick` are declared). But this is somehow not working. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Currently I have (in my main.c file):

```
static volatile int i = 0; 
Interrupt_Handler() {
    i++;
}
static int getValuei(void) {
    return i;
}
```

and in my Interrupt.c file, I have:

```
extern void Interrupt_Handler(void);
extern int getValuei(void);
```

Result: `i` is not incremented in Interrupt Handler and the code stops.

Comment: "Is somehow not working" is a pretty useless description of what exactly does not work and what symptoms you see. Show your code, describe expected and observed behavior.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I've updated my post with the code that I tested it out with.

Comment: There are only two problems that I can see here. One is that the access to `i` from `getValuei` isn't necessarily atomic, depending on CPU. The other is that `i` will eventually overflow and invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Have you debugged your program, and checked that it actually enters your interrupt handler? Perhaps it is executing a different interrupt handler instead of yours (usually the default one is meant to halt the program execution, so you can check what has happened). Also, having declared your interrupt handler in the Interrupt.c file is not enough. You have to register it with its corresponding interrupt

Comment: why is `getValuei()` `static`? Very probably, you cannot access it from Interrupt.c

Comment: Is the interrupt being executed though?
Regarding readability, if you have created a function to get the value, why not another to update the value?

Comment: What code "stops"? You have not provided any code that might do that on its own.  That issue may be unrelated to `i` not incrementing, or `i` may not be incrementing _becauise_ the code fails in some other way before that can happen.   Your question starts describing `extern volatile int counter;`, which then does not feature in your code.

Comment: Did you noticed, what @tofro mentioned ? Qualifying `getValuei` as extern has no impact (by default 'C' functions have global scope), and you've declared it as static. Remove static qualifier here.

Comment: I am pretty sure the code wouldn’t even compile as is

Answer (score 0):

I do this a lot, using global variables in an interrupt routine, for example msec counter used in a timer routine.

What I should do is declare the interrupt handler and the global variable in the Interrupt.c file. Don't make the variable static, you want to use it outside your file.

One of the hardest points is to make sure your interrupt is really called. Most of the time you have to enable this particular interrupt, but also enable global interrupts. Sometimes at the end of the interrupt you have to enable it again.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that using volatile like this is not correct. It will work 99% of the time but when it does not you will have a really hard time finding why.

Access to i even if just for reading is NOT atomic and so i might change while you are in the middle of reading it.

Source:

[Item 6](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/28) and
[Beyond volatile](https://www.iar.com/support/resources/articles/beyond-volatile/)